# I am trying to initilize request inside a function which is scheduled but the initiliation of request is not working?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

i am trying to initilize HttpServletRequest inside the function which is scheduled and perform actions according to the cron job . but the function stopped after initilized the request . what should i do now  ?
i am working on spring mvc . this my code :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")
@Async
public void PerformActionFunction() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("hello 1");
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        System.out.println("hello 2");

    ModelMap model =  new ModelMap();

    FunctionForDate(request,model);


}
```

the output prints hello 1 but it does not prints hello 2 . the function stopped after initilized the HttpServletRequest . what should i do now .

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. As the javadoc of `RequestContextHolder` states

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound
>   `RequestAttributes` object.

In other words, the request handling thread of the Servlet container stores the `RequestAttributes` in a `static` `ThreadLocal` field of the `RequestContextHolder`. If you are in the same thread, you can then again retrieve it through this holder.

However, since you have an `@Async`/`@Scheduled` (it should really be only one or the other) method, that method is being invoked on a completely different thread. It doesn't have access to any of the values of other threads' `ThreadLocal`s.

Comment: is there any solution for this problem , so that i can use HttpServletRequest object inside this thread ?

Comment: @RajeshRamawat No. That'll become more obvious when you answer the question _which `HttpServletRequest` object_?

Comment: i mean how can i use HttpServletRequest object inside the @scheduled function (which is PerformActionFunction()  according to my question .) ?

Comment: @RajeshRamawat I'm telling you you cannot.